# Does symlink function in perl overwrite an existing link

Tags: perl, symlink

I'm trying to mimic the Unix command

```
ln -sf /path/to/file /path/to/link
```

by using Perl

```
symlink (/path/to/file /path/to/link)
```

Does Perl remove existing destination file and creates the symlink similar to -s -f options ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`symlink` simply calls the OS call by the same name (`symlink(2)`), which returns error `EEXIST` when "`newpath` already exists".

If you wanted to implement `-f`, you could use

```
unlink($new_qfn);
symlink($old_qfn, $new_qfn)
   or die("Can't create symlink \"$new_qfn\": $!\n");
```

However, the following does a better job of handling race conditions:

```
if (!symlink($old_qfn, $new_qfn)) {
   if ($!{EEXIST}) {
      unlink($new_qfn)
         or die("Can't remove \"$new_qfn\": $!\n");
      symlink($old_qfn, $new_qfn)
         or die("Can't create symlink \"$new_qfn\": $!\n");
   } else {
      die("Can't create symlink \"$new_qfn\": $!\n");
   }
}
```

`ln` uses the latter approach.

```
$ strace ln -sf a b
...
symlink("a", "b")                       = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
unlink("b")                             = 0
symlink("a", "b")                       = 0
...
```

Comment: Thats a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: In both cases a new i-node is created, never realized that.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple to figure out yourself. Let's try it on

```
ls -li link_to_FILE.txt
# 2415940160 lrwxrwxrwx.  ...  link_to_FILE.txt -> FILE.txt
```

with

```
perl -wE'symlink "FILE.txt", "link_to_FILE.txt" or warn "Cant make it: $!"'
```

It prints

```
Cant make it: File exists at -e line 1.
```

and I check that the original file (link) with the same inode number is still there.

So, no, it won't overwrite an existing file.

The page for [symlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/symlink.html) indicates that there are no options to **f**orce that.

Comment: You force it by unlinking the target symlink name first.

Comment: @mob, `symlink`+`rm`+`symlink` does a better job of handling race conditions in the common scenario. This is what `ln` uses.